# Setting EF interceptor file name layout

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6

In EF 6.1 (onwards) I can configure my app.config file like the following :

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="C:\Stuff\LogOutput.txt"/>
      <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/>
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

Above resides in the EntityFramework section of my app.config.

How would I be able to set the layout of the filename to reflect the date of the operation similar to popular loggers like NLog so I get new log per day?

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\logs\folder\log_${shortdate}.txt" layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5} [${threadid:padding=3}] ${logger:padding=-55} - ${message}" />
```

Is such facility available without the need for some coding and recompilation?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code for EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Interception/DatabaseLogger.cs), that is not possible with the simple logger. You will need to implement your own interceptor to do this.

```
// Code from EF6 source:
public DatabaseLogger(string path, bool append)
{
    Check.NotEmpty(path, "path");
    _writer = new StreamWriter(path, append) { AutoFlush = true };
}
```

Comment: well if so this should be added as comment. He already said this ***without the need for some coding and recompilation***. I'm pretty sure that he also knows how to use code to do this.

Comment: The question is whether such a facility is available. The answer is "No, and here's why".

Comment: You don't need to even post that code, it's obvious that it accepts just a `path` and a `bool`. That's all. Everything can be put in a simple comment. He asks like that but actually he hopes some answer ***solving*** his problem will be posted. Also I think there may be some work-around for him which should be acceptable. Try starting from this ***without the need for some coding and recompilation***, we can find some work-around (Of course it would be totally stuck with the default `DatabaseLogger`.

Comment: I posted the code snippet to verify that it's a simple string path that is a direct constructor property (no processing at all). In some configuration sections (ex web.config paths), there are property variables that get substituted. EF6.1 does not have said facility for dates or other variables.

Comment: Yes, you could do some sort of crazy workaround like a scheduled task that uses XSL to reparse your config file to set the logfile name to include the date. However this is seriously kludgy, and I would personally never allow such a hack in a production environment.